# Adding more questions to database for test app

Tags: java, android, database

I am developing an android learning app and I have a problem. I cannot update the questions in the database. It is only can show the first five questions from the database. And this is my database code, is there someone who can help me? Thanks

```
package com.example.learningapp.test;

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Test";
// tasks table name
private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
// tasks Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
private static final String KEY_ans1= "Ans1"; //option a
private static final String KEY_ans2= "Ans2"; //option b
private static final String KEY_ans3= "Ans3"; //option c
private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    dbase=db;
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_ans1 +" TEXT, "
            +KEY_ans2 +" TEXT, "+KEY_ans3+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);        
    addQuestions();
    //db.close();
}

private void addQuestions()
{
    Question q1=new Question("Tumbuhan memerlukan cahaya matahari untuk" +
            " _________________.","Bernafas", "Hidup", "Membuat Makanan", "Membuat Makanan");
    this.addQuestion(q1);
    Question q2=new Question("Manusia memerlukan empat keperluan asas, " +
            "terdiri daripada", "Udara, Makanan, Cahaya Matahari, Air", "Air, Udara, Makanan, Tempat Perlindungan", 
            "Udara, Tempat Perlindungan, Cahaya Matahari, Air", "Air, Udara, Makanan, Tempat Perlindungan");
    this.addQuestion(q2);
    Question q3=new Question("Sisa-sisa makanan disingkirkan keluar melalui dubur" +
            " sebagai tinja.Proses ini dinamakan ______________?","Penyahtinjaan", "Perkumuhan","Pernafasan","Penyahtinjaan");
    this.addQuestion(q3);
    Question q4=new Question("Semasa menarik nafas, dada akan _____________ dan _____________." +
            " Pada masa yang sama, udara masuk ke peparu.", "naik, mengembang", "naik turun, menghempis", "naik, menghempis","naik, mengembang");
    this.addQuestion(q4);
    Question q5=new Question("Berikut adalah cara tumbuhan melindungi diri" +
            " daripada musuh, KECUALI","Bergetah","Beracun","Daun jejarum","Daun jejarum");
    this.addQuestion(q5);
    Question q6= new Question("Pilihkan jawapan proses kitar hidup" +
            "rama-rama yang betul.", "telur-> kepompong-> larva->rama-rama dewasa", "telur-> larva-> kepompong-> rama-rama dewasa",
            "telur-> pupa-> larva -> rama-rama dewasa", "telur-> larva-> kepompong-> rama-rama dewasa");
    this.addQuestion(q6);
    Question q7= new Question("Pilihkan jawapan proses kitar hidup" +
            "katak yang betul.", "telur-> berudu-> katak muda-> katak dewasa", "telur-> katak muda-> katak dewasa-> kepompong",
            "telur-> pupa-> katak muda ->katak dewasa", "telur-> berudu-> katak muda-> katak dewasa");
    this.addQuestion(q7);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
// Adding new question
public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
    //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION()); 
    values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
    values.put(KEY_ans1, quest.getans1());
    values.put(KEY_ans2, quest.getans2());
    values.put(KEY_ans3, quest.getans3());
    // Inserting Row
    dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);        
}
public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
    List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
    dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Question quest = new Question();
            quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
            quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
            quest.setans1(cursor.getString(3));
            quest.setans2(cursor.getString(4));
            quest.setans3(cursor.getString(5));
            quesList.add(quest);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return quest list
    return quesList;
}

public int rowcount()
{
    int row=0;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    row=cursor.getCount();
    return row;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your questions in `onCreate`. It was called already at first start. It seems like you've added another questions later. You can upgrade database or uninstall the application and install it again to trigger database creation second time. Anyway it is not good practice to fill your values in `onCreate`.

Comment: hi, Evgeniy...Thanks for the suggestion. But I have try to update the database version from 1 to 2, but it does not seem work. It still output with the first five questions from the database.

Comment: post a screenshot maybe ?

Comment: You mean screenshot for the output? when the question display until question 5. It cant proceed to the question 6 again. When i click on Next button, the result of rating will display.